# How to check value of item is not equal to zero before adding in a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of double list1 and list2. And I am comparing both lists and interested in indices of items from list1 matched items from list2. I am using below linq expression:

```
List<double>  list1 = new List<double> () {1.0 , 2.0 , 5.0 , 7.0 , 8.0} ;
List<double> list2 = new List<double> () {2.0 ,7.0 ,9.0} ;
List<int> kk= new List <int> () ;
list2.ForEach (xx => kk.Add (list1.Select((v, i) => new { v, i }).Where(x => x.v == xx).Select(x => x.i).FirstOrDefault ()));
```

I have one issue with above statement if item from list2 does not exist in list1 then I get 0 value in return and this zero value added in list kk. How can it be avoided to add 0 values in  list kk.

Comment: You could use `AddRange` and `Take(1)` instead of `Add` and `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem, because you are selecting default value (zero) if match is not found. I suggest you to use [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it's also faster than iterating inner sequence for each item in outer sequence (O(N) instead of searching in :

```
from x in list1.Select((l1,i) => new { l1, i })
join l2 in list2 on x.l1 equals l2
select x.i
```

Or lambda syntax:

```
list1.Select((l1,i) => new { l1, i })
     .Join(list2, x => x.l1, l2 => l2, (x, l2) => x.i);
```

Internally Join creates lookup for inner sequence (list2 in this case) - that takes single iteration over inner sequence. Then we need one iteration over outer sequence to get joined inner items from lookup. Something like:

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
    IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter, TInner TResult> resultSelector)
{
     var lookup = inner.ToLookup(innerKeySelector); // iterate over list2

     foreach(var outerItem in outer)
     {
          var joined = lookup[outerKeySelector(outerItem)]; // quick search, O(1)
          if (!joined.Any())
              continue; // go to next outer item if no matches exist

          foreach(var joindeItem in joined) // iterate over matches
              yield return resultSelector(outerItem, joinedItem); // return index
     }
}
```

Actual implementation is a little more optimized, but core idea is same.

Comment: Can you explain, how join method is working in this scenario. I want to use custom equal method for comparing equal values.

Comment: @User1551892 sure, I was in the middle of adding this to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is busy with finding the index of a given element in a list. `List<T>` already has a method `IndexOf` which returns the index if it finds the item and  `-1` if it doesn't.

If you don't care about performance (runtime is `list1.Count * list2.Count`) you could use:

```
kk = list2.Select(xx => list1.IndexOf(xx)).Where(i => (i >= 0)).ToList();
```

If performance matters, you'll need to transform `list1` with a `Dictionary<double, int>` reducing the runtime to `list1.Count + list2.Count`.

Comment: I am dealing with doubles and I have to think about precision and I am using custom equal method for comparing doubles. Due to which I am not using Indexof method.